# Using group.order of the likert package with a vector as a filter

Tags: r, likert

I have computed the likert results of my survey. They look like this:

```
       Item        1         2         3         4         5
1    [3][1] likert_scale  0.00000  14.28571  14.28571  57.14286  14.28571
2    [3][2] likert_scale  0.00000   0.00000  28.57143  42.85714  28.57143
3    [3][3] likert_scale  0.00000   0.00000   0.00000 100.00000   0.00000
4    [3][4] likert_scale  0.00000   0.00000  28.57143  42.85714  28.57143
5    [3][5] likert_scale  0.00000  14.28571  28.57143  42.85714  14.28571
6    [4][1] likert_scale  0.00000  14.28571  42.85714  42.85714   0.00000
7    [4][2] likert_scale 14.28571  42.85714  14.28571  28.57143   0.00000
```

Now I would like to plot only some of the results, according to the row. i.e. all rows with [3] together. How can do that with group.order? I have also a vector already with the TRUE and FALSE results.

```
likertgroup1 <- grepl( "\\[3\\]\\[" , names( final_likerts )) 
str(likertgroup1)
likert.bar.plot(reslikert,group.order = likertgroup1,center=3)
```

Thank you in advance.

The data for likertgroup1:

```
c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
```

And for reslikert (an excerpt because it is very long)

```
NA_integer_
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), `[20][5] likert_scale` = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_,
```

Comment: please provide your data with `dput()`

Comment: @wusel I added it above.

Comment: check out [the answers her](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362) an dconsider `dput(head(yourdata))` so we can reproduce your problem. Without proper data its all very cumbersome